# Change array taken from reactjs context locally without updating the actual array in context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-context

I'm quite new to using the context in react.
I have a array of objects held in context similar to this:

```
allQueries: [
  {
    id: 0,
    operator: 'AND',
    field: 'current_full_path',
    from: 'xyz',
    to: '',
    selection: '',
    addDisabled: true,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    operator: 'AND',
    field: 'user',
    from: 'Bob',
    to: '',
    selection: '',
    addDisabled: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    operator: 'AND',
    field: 'package_type',
    from: '',
    to: '',
    selection: 'large',
    addDisabled: true,
  },
  {
    etc...
  }
],
```

A version of this will be sent off as the body of a request to a server which will return a data set based on the query.

The problem I'm having is cleaning up the above prior to sending. I need to remove the 'id' field, the 'addDisabled' field etc. etc. and I need to do it without changing the *actual* array of objects held in context because it needs to be used again afterwards.

I've tried populating local state with the array from context and carrying out the changes there. I've also tried setting it to an empty array in a new context and making changes to that, however, whatever I do, the original allQueries array keeps getting updated as well, meaning that users can't make refinements to their search after the initial search has been made.

I'm, stumped with this - has anyone got any ideas?

ps  - as stated above, currently trying to move it to a different context to get round this - for fuller detail the full component code is below:

Thanks

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import AndQueryContext from '../../context/andQuery/andQueryContext';
import SendQueryContext from '../../context/sendQuery/sendQueryContext';

const SearchButton = () => {
  const andQueryContext = useContext(AndQueryContext);
  const sendQueryContext = useContext(SendQueryContext);

  const { allQueries } = andQueryContext;
  const { objToSend, updateObjToSend } = sendQueryContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    updateObjToSend(allQueries);
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [allQueries]);

  const prepareQuery = (objToSend) => {
    console.clear('objToSend: ', objToSend);
    const queryObj = {};

    prepareAndQueries(objToSend, queryObj);
    console.log('queryObj after: ', queryObj);

  };

  const prepareAndQueries = (objToSend, queryObj) => {
    console.log('objToSend: ', objToSend);
    objToSend.map((item, index) => {
      delete item.id;
      delete item.addDisabled;
      if (
        item.field === 'package_type' ||
        item.field === 'document_type' ||
        item.field === 'user' ||
        item.field === 'status'
      ) {
        delete item.from;
        delete item.to;
      }
      if (
        item.field === 'current_full_path' ||
        item.field === 'date' ||
        item.field === 'size'
      ) {
        delete item.selection;
      }
    });

    console.log('objToSend after filter: ', objToSend);
    console.log('allQueries after filter: ', allQueries);

    queryObj.initial = objToSend;

    return queryObj;
  };

  return (
    <div className='col-2'>
      <button
        className='btn btn-labelled btn-info btn-sm'
        onClick={(e) => prepareQuery(objToSend)}
      >
        <span className='btn-label'>
          <i className='fas fa-search'></i>
        </span>
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchButton;
```

The context hook brings in another file AndQueryState.js:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
// import axios from 'axios';
import AndQueryContext from './andQueryContext';
import AndQueryReducer from './andQueryReducer';

import {
  UPDATE_ALL_QUERIES,
  UPDATE_DROPDOWN_ARRAY,
  UPDATE_REMOVED_DROPDOWN,
  UPDATE_USE_OR,
  // SEND_QUERY,
} from '../types';

const AndQueryState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    initialQuery: {
      id: 0,
      operator: 'AND',
      field: 'current_full_path',
      from: '',
      to: '',
      selection: '',
      addDisabled: true,
    },
    allQueries: [
      {
        id: 0,
        operator: 'AND',
        field: 'current_full_path',
        from: '',
        to: '',
        selection: '',
        addDisabled: true,
      },
    ],
    dropDownFieldsInitial: [
      'current_full_path',
      'date',
      'size',
      'package_type',
      'document_type',
      'user',
      'status',
    ],
    dropDownFields: [
      'current_full_path',
      'date',
      'size',
      'package_type',
      'document_type',
      'user',
      'status',
    ],
    // old ones
    sendToApi: 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=stefemil',
    loading: false,
    useOr: 0, // determines whether OR clauses are to be used
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AndQueryReducer, initialState);

  const updateAllQueries = (allQueriesFromComp) => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_ALL_QUERIES,
      payload: allQueriesFromComp,
    });
  };

  const updateDropDownArray = (filteredDropDownFields) => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_DROPDOWN_ARRAY,
      payload: filteredDropDownFields,
    });
  };

  const updateRemovedDropDown = (dropDownOption) => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_REMOVED_DROPDOWN,
      payload: dropDownOption, // need to do this to stop it sticking an array within an array
    });
  };

  const updateUseOr = (updatedUseOr) => {
    console.log('useOr passed from component: ', updatedUseOr);
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_USE_OR,
      payload: updatedUseOr, // need to do this to stop it sticking an array within an array
    });
  };

  return (
    <AndQueryContext.Provider
      value={{
        initialQuery: state.initialQuery,
        allQueries: state.allQueries,
        dropDownFieldsInitial: state.dropDownFieldsInitial,
        dropDownFields: state.dropDownFields,
        dropDownRemoved: state.dropDownRemoved,
        useOr: state.useOr,
        loading: state.loading,
        updateAllQueries,
        updateDropDownArray,
        updateRemovedDropDown,
        updateUseOr,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AndQueryContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AndQueryState;
```

Comment: is `andQueryContext` is hook? can you add code of `andQueryContext` too?

Comment: Added - see above, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the answer lay in the fact that refs get passed from context so if you update something taken from context, no matter if you've assigned it to a new constant, the original will update as well.

I got around this by pulling the query into a file in my contexts folder, JSON.stringify-ing it and then parsing the JSON. This seems to break the chain of references. I could then make changes to the arrays without affecting the original.

The function I used to make changes in the state file is as follows:

```
const prepareQueryToSend = (queryObj) => {
    const strung = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
    console.log(strung);
    const unstrung = JSON.parse(strung);
    console.log(unstrung);

    unstrung.initial.map((item, index) => {
      delete item.id;
      delete item.addDisabled;
      if (
        item.field === 'package_type' ||
        item.field === 'document_type' ||
        item.field === 'user' ||
        item.field === 'status'
      ) {
        delete item.from;
        delete item.to;
      }
      if (
        item.field === 'current_full_path' ||
        item.field === 'date' ||
        item.field === 'size'
      ) {
        delete item.selection;
      }
    });

    unstrung.OR.map((item, index) => {
      item.map((item2, index2) => {
        delete item2.id;
        delete item2.addDisabled;
        return item2;
      });

      return item;
    });

    console.log('unstrung after: ', unstrung);

    const restrung = JSON.stringify(unstrung);

    console.log(restrung);
  };
```

Comment: Stef won't this be very slow , consider running so many operations in map, on every single element , the if statements and all that?

Comment: Works fine - instantaneous in fact

Comment: Its fine, it's not being used for large arrays

Comment: Oh, I thought the query array was quite large, but you should consider implementing like one I have suggest, check my new answer..

Answer (score -1):

Well as per the question you want to perform something like this:

```
list = [{name: "Jane",disabled:true},{name:"Austin", disabled: true}]
```

to:

```
newList = [{name: "Jane"},{name:"Austin"}]
```

It is very simple you can use the `Array.map` function...

```js
list = [{name: "Jane"},{name: "Austin"},{name:"Pearl"}];
newList = list.map((item)=>{
   // whatever you want to set;
 
return {
    name: item.name
};
})
console.log("old list:",list);
console.log("new list:",newList);
```

The problem with copying entire list items into new list is that the reference of each item gets copied into the list not the item hence making changes to copied item are passed to the original list.
You can refer to what are references for more understanding.

Comment: No, it's actually the other way round... list = [{name: "Jane",disabled:false},{name:"Austin", disabled: true}] needs to change to: newList = [{name: "Jane"},{name: "Austin"} ...] - mapping an array isn;t the problem, ive done that 100s off times... the issue is, as you mention with the reference being copied to.

Comment: Stef is this just with disabled or with many paramaters that you don't want...

Comment: You can do something like el=>{name:el.name,date:el.date}

Comment: Thanks - but I got it sorted - will post an answer here in a sec. Cheers